# How to convert String with " character to URL

Tags: swift, string, url

How to convert String like "fff\"fff" to URL?
URL must contain " character and be like "ff"ff"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You escape the `"` character to `%22`. The easiest way to do that is via `URLComponents`:

```
var components = URLComponents(string: "https://somewhere.com")!
components.query = "ff\"ff"

let url = components.url! // https://somewhere.com?ff%22ff
```